# Choosing deployment scenarios for composite, web based .NET apps

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, deployment, iis-7.5

I have a .NET v4 application consisting of a web application (ASP.NET MVC2) and several web services (WCF). During development I have deployed the app to IIS 7.5 using  /app1/ for web application and /app1/services/serviceXX.svc for web services...However, for production deployment I would like to find out if it would be better to deploy these apps into separate web sites and host each from root context.

So here are some of the scenarios, I am thinking of and was wondering if someone can share some pros and cons of each...

### Scenario 1 (app per web site)

Deploy each app to a seaparate Web Site under IIS 7.5 ad use root context (/). I can then assign separate app pools for each site.
For example:

```
http://app1.domain.com/         <-- ASP.NET MVC2 app #1
http://app1svc.domain.com/      <-- WCF services related to app #1
http://app2.domain.com/         <-- ASP.NET MVC2 app #2
http://app2svc.domain.com/      <-- WCF services related to app #2
...
```

### Scenario 2 (web app per web site, all services for all apps in one web site)

In this scenario, each web app is deployed just like in scenario 1 but all web services for all apps are deployed in single web site of iis 7.5.
I am guessing, advantage in this case is that only 1 web site has to have WCF bindings
For example:

```
http://app1.domain.com/         <-- ASP.NET MVC2 app #1
http://app2.domain.com/         <-- ASP.NET MVC2 app #2
http://services.domain.com/app1/    <-- WCF services related to app #1
http://services.domain.com/app2/    <-- WCF services related to app #2
...
```

### Scenario 3  ( one IIS web site with sub-context for each app)

In this scenario there is only 1 IIS web site and each application is deployed in sub-context (this is what I use during development).
This approach (seems?) simple and easier to administer than other 2 but I am not sure...
For example:

```
http://apps.domain.com/app1/                <-- ASP.NET MVC2 app #1
http://apps.domain.com/app1/services/svc1/      <-- WCF service #1 related to app #1
http://apps.domain.com/app1/services/svc2/      <-- WCF service #2 related to app #1
http://apps.domain.com/app2/                <-- ASP.NET MVC2 app #2
http://apps.domain.com/app2/services/svc1/      <-- WCF service #1 related to app #2
http://apps.domain.com/app2/services/svc2/      <-- WCF service #2 related to app #2
...
```

I am thinking that Scenario #1, although a bit more involved, is the most flexible as I can controll the bindings, limits, and other properties which are only available on a web site level.
What do others think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1 is the most flexible in some ways, yes. If you have any issues where any single app and it's web service needs more resources, it would be very easy to do so since multiple apps are not tied together on any single URL. It's easiest, IMO, to keep every app in its own app pool with this option.

Option 2 may be good; you could scale the entire 'services architecture' out for the collective needs of all the apps, as opposed to one or another. But that can be bad as well; if you have a small number of the apps whose services are getting higher use (as opposed to it being somewhat more 'level' in distribution), it may make more sense to be able to scale up only those services which need it individually. But honestly, I'm not sure how valuable that is.

Option 3, IMO, is the best option if you expect that all the individual apps might need to scale up together; That is, you don't expect to have a very small number of the individual apps that need considerably more resources than the rest. But even if you do, say, have just one that is much busier than the rest, this would still enable you to scale the entire app up. But with an extreme mismatch between needs of the separate apps, it might not work out so well.

---

I think ultimately it may really come down to what will be easier for you to manage, though. Will creating new sites or new virtual dirs/apps fit better with your expected growth?

Comment: I don't expect having 100s of apps, so management is not a big deal for me. Due to its flexibility, I am 90% sold on Solution 1 already, I just wanted to see if there is a real valid reason not do to it or to choose other Solutions over it...If that makes sense...